# Confusion regarding distance and transfer of energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

$W = Fs\cos{θ}$

I'm not sure about the relation between distance and transfer of energy.

If I have an object in which 2 forces are being applied in the same direction, causing the object to move a distance $\bf{s}$, but one force is several orders of magnitude bigger than the other. How do you calculate the work performed by each force individually? do they perform the same work, same transfer of energy?

Another example, two opposing equal forces on a static object. Is there no energy transfer in this system? and work done by each individual force?

I don't understand this. For example, if I have an electric motor fixed in place exerting a force against a static object, the battery will run out regardless of the motor not moving (in an AC induction motor you can keep generating a rotating magnetic field that exerts a force independently of the movement of the rotor).

Answer (score 1):

The work done by each force, when two different forces push an object the same way, is as always force times displacement. The smaller force does less work but over the same distance.

In your example of balanced forces and a depleting battery, note that no work is being done on the object but work is still being done within the battery. Internally. Therefor the battery depletes eventually.

Similarly, if you push on a wall, you also move it nowhere. No work is done on the wall. Still, you eventually feel tired. Because your body did spend energy internally on muscle contraction etc.

There are many such "machines" that spend energy just to produce a force. Like a rocket engine spending fuel even while it isn't thrusting. In such cases the energy is spent on internal work and on reorganising internal chemical or physiological structures. But no work is done on the external object of it isn't moved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if that's the case with the motor and batt unless something else is happening.  But even so electric and magnetic fields can "move" irrespective of objects moving.  The Poynting vector $S=E×B$ (up to a factor depending on units) describes the direction of energy flow out of the system, and would be non zero in your case.   And the momentum of the fields is equal to $\ epsilon \ mu$ times the Poynting vector.  The point is that in electromagnetic fields, force and momentum and energy can be non obvious.  You can be doing work without matter moving if the fields are

Comment: You cannot be doing work If matter is not moving. The poynting vector describes energy flux. Not work.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you calculate the work performed by each force individually?

Forces are vector quantities and are therefore subject to vector addition. Thus the two forces can be added together to form one equivalent force. If both forces act in the same direction, then equivalent force is the sum of the magnitudes of the individual forces,

$$F_{eq}=F_{1}+F_{2}$$

And the total work done is the sum of the work done by each force, or

$$W_{tot}=F_{eq}s=F_{1}s+F_{2}s$$

> do they perform the same work, same transfer of energy?

Since both forces are contact forces acting in the same direction they are constrained to act over the same distance. Therefore they will only do the same amount of work (transfer the same energy to the object) if the magnitude of both forces is the same.

> Another example, two opposing equal forces on a static object. Is
> there no energy transfer in this system? and work done by each
> individual force?

Since the net force is zero, no work is done *on the object*.

> I don't understand this. For example, if I have an electric motor
> fixed in place exerting a force against a static object, the battery
> will run out regardless of the motor not moving

The battery will run out because even though the motor does no work on the object, the battery continues to deliver current to the motor coils resulting in $I_{2}R$ heating.

> (in an AC induction motor you can keep generating a rotating magnetic
> field that exerts a force independently of the movement of the rotor)

Again, even though the motor does no work on an object, energy is still dissipated internally in the motor in the form of $I^{2}R$ heating of the coils.

Hope this helps.